# Atribuir função do jQuery a variável em operador ternário

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou criando uma função simples de avançar/voltar em um formulário com "steps" e gostaria de implementar uma solução mais eficaz a situação abaixo:

```
$('.botao').click(function(){
 if($(this).hasClass('avancar')) {
   $('.container').next()
 } else {
   $('.container').prev()
 }
})
```

Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de fazer algo como:

```
$('.botao').click(function(){
  const action = $(this).hasClass('avancar') ? next() : prev();
  $('.container').action;
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu código em nenhum momento deixa de ser eficaz por estar utilizando `if`/`else`.

Você perderá legibilidade se quiser deixar de utilizá-los em situações como essa. Mas você pode, sim, utilizar um operador ternário.

Basta determinar uma string com o nome do método que você quer acessar utilizando o operador ternário e obter o valor da propriedade (no caso será uma função) utilizando a [notação de colchetes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_colchete), para no final invocá-la.

Assim:

```js
$('.botao').click(function () {
  $('.container')[$(this).hasClass('avancar') ? 'next' : 'prev']();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ser possível é, agora se isso é algo bom eu já não sei, entendo o porque isso pode parecer interessante mas a leitura do código depois pode ser prejudicada. De qualquer modo, você pode fazer isso seguindo um dos modelos abaixo.

Primeiro, ao chamar a função `next()` ou `prev()` ou qualquer outra com os parenteses, você não esta atribuindo a variável a função em si, mas sim o resultado dessas função, então para atribuir uma função a uma variável você não deve colocar os parenteses  final dela. Outro ponto importante, essas funções pertencem a um objeto do JQuery, então você não pode chama-las diretamente, para acessar uma função do JQuery sem chamar a mesma você pode fazer o seguinte `$.fn.next`

agora você tem a função armazenada na variável `action` mas não pode chama-la deste modo `$('.container').action`, isso porque action não é uma propriedade do JQuery para ser chamado a partir de um objeto do mesmo, você precisa chamar a função armazenada em action e criar o contexto do objeto necessário para ser executado, você pode fazer isso usando a propriedade `call` que as funções possuem, então seu código final seria parecido com isso:

```
const action = $(this).hasClass('avancar') ? $.fn.next : $.fn.prev;
action.call($('.container'));
```

Outro modo de fazer algo parecido com o que você quer é usar um if ternário para chamar diretamente as funções next e prev do objeto, seria algo como o seguinte:

```
$(this).hasClass('avancar') ? $('.container').next() : $('.container').prev();
```

Comment: Boa resposta, mas usar o `call` para algo assim é matar formiga com bazuca, né? :-D

Comment: Isso é verdade kkkkk, havia esquecido dos colchetes para fazer isso, a sua resposta é mais elegante com certeza :D

Comment: Que nada, elegante mesmo é usar `if`/`else` sem invenção de moda, rsrs. :D

Comment: Muito obrigado @LuizFelipe e mauricio-andre . Acabei optando pela resposta do Luiz levando em conta o próprio comentário do Maurício.

Aqui eu ainda executo mais ações do que o do exemplo acima, aí me pareceu fazer mais sentido salvar numa variável, mas entendo o ponto de vocês.

Muito obrigado!